# Просмотр контролов в цикле foreach

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c#

В чем может быть проблема? Идут 2 цикла подряд - достаем контролы из панели. В первом случае находит 14 контролов, во втором 7. Если убрать строку GrContril.Add_Control(cont); выводит тоже 14.

```
foreach (LayerItems cont in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
     MessageBox.Show(cont.layerName);
     i++;
}
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
foreach (LayerItems cont in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    MessageBox.Show(cont.layerName);
    GrContril.Add_Control(cont);
}
```

Comment: Просто в качестве догадки: GrContril.Add_Control(cont) может выбрасывать исключения, если это происходит, цикл прерывается, не успев просчитать все элементы. И возможно, надежней будет считать не вызовами MessageBox, а печатями в отладочную консоль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо!

```
flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.CopyTo(LayerMas, 0);

int count = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count;

for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
    GrContril.Add_Control(LayerMas[j]);
}
flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(true);
```

Comment: Кстати, если этот код работает, то и foreach по LayerMas должен работать.

Answer (score 1):

Так вы должно быть перекладываете контролы в другой контейнер.. вот их и становится меньше.. разве не так?

Comment: Да, это я уже понял.. Спасибо. А как можно переложить все? Пробовал в массив записать - тоже самое..

Comment: Коллекцию можно скопировать в массив путем вызова метода CopyTo. Затем пройтись по массиву и добавить каждый элемент.

Comment: А не скажете, почему когда передаешь через copyTo или просто через массив, контрол передается не корректно?

Comment: @Mamont Если прорисовка неправильная, то перед добавлением рекомендуется вызвать SuspendLayout, а после добавления - ResumeLayout.